# Angular add additional external files on build

Tags: angular

Is there a way to download or package additional files say assets likes images or json files into the final build at compile time?

I am trying to find a way I can have the files packed to the server if they are managed from a separate CMS system.

Or is it best to just try to find a way to integrate CMS into github so when content changes it deploys automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding files in the `assets` property in the angular.json. When you create a build, `angular` will automatically add these files in the build folder. For example:

```
 "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "config.json"
      ],
```

Or

```
"assets": ["addfileshere"]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a away to add files which are from a webserver or some other external location? I can only find ways to add assets manually.

Comment: For that you can use gulp, it does provide copy. Create a folder add files to that from external source. Add gulp copy command to the build command. So, when you create a build this extra command will help you copy things from external directory. You should use append command. If you need more help, I can add to the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! How I've missed this up till now I just don't know. Thank you! Gulp allows me to package up the content I need based on my dynamic requirements.